# Use sed command to wrap strings

Tags: c++, windows, string, visual-studio, sed

I have a C++ program where I want to wrap most strings in a MACRO.

For example, the code:

```
#include "header.h"

const char* str;

if (func("Hello, world", "Goodbye", "world") && 
    func(MACRO("Hello, world"), "Hello"))
{
    str = "MACRO(\"didIt\")";
}
```

Should become:

```
#include "header.h"

const char* str;

if (func(MACRO("Hello, world"), MACRO("Goodbye"), MACRO("world")) && 
    func(MACRO("Hello, world"), MACRO("Hello")))
{
    str = MACRO("MACRO(\"didIt\")");
}
```

Note that if the string is already inside the MACRO, it should not be double wrapped. Also, if the string is part of a preprocessor statement, it should not be modified.

I've tried using sed to do this, but I can't quite get it right. I'm new to sed, so it may be that I'm just not doing it right or that sed can't do this.

I'm running on Windows and using Visual studio if that helps. I installed a sed utility on my Windows computer thinking this would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a preprocessor statement in your example code, which should not be modified.

Comment: I posted one. Maybe I don't understand what you are seeking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want *negative lookbehind*, which `sed` doesn't support.  Use a more powerful tool, like python, something like:

```
cat prog.cpp | python -c 'import re,sys;for line in sys.stdin: print re.sub(r\''\'(?<!MACRO\()"([^"]*)\''\',"MACRO(\"\g<1>\"))'
```

Comment: Ah, too bad. I'll probably just create a C++ program to do it. Installing and learning another language seems like overkill IMHO. Good to know I can't do this.